# SQL Server 2008 Filestream Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, filestream, updates

On my local Windows XP machine, I'm not able any more to create databases with FILESTREAM.

[alt text http://img379.imageshack.us/img379/9899/errorv.jpg](http://img379.imageshack.us/img379/9899/errorv.jpg)

This error is caused by one of these security updates from MS:

- KB952004
- KB923561
- KB961373
- KB956572
- KB959426
- KB960863

Does anybody know how to resolve the problem WITHOUT removing the security updates?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem.  Finally found a workaround from http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=435855.  You have to run the sql server service as a user different from Network service.  This may cause other problems later... but at least the FILESTREAM-enabled database can be created and we can go on to create tables and data and learn this new feature.